# How to see components in toolbox after adding a new reference?

Tags: c#, wpftoolkit, visibility, toolbox

In my project I add reference on the WPFToolkit assembly, restart Visual Studio and has not seen WPFToolkit components in my VS ToolBox window. What I do wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Toolbox doesn't automatically pick up components/controls in referenced assemblies. It does however automatically pick up components/controls that are built in your projects.

You can right click the toolbox and choose "Customize" and you will get a dialog that lets you browse to the assembly and check off any controls that you want to appear. It might be helpful to create a new tab in the toolbox first.