# Can I add a custom UserControl library to the Visual Studio toolbox if it references another assembly?

Tags: .net, winforms, visual-studio-2012, user-controls

I have a dll containing several UserControls that I would like to share between multiple Visual Studio Solutions. I can't seem to add the controls to my toolbox in another Solution by: right-clicking the toolbox, selecting 'Customize' and browsing to the assembly (as described here: [How to see components in toolbox after adding a new reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2490471/how-to-see-components-in-toolbox-after-adding-a-new-reference))

The problem seems to be that my UserControls are in an assembly that is referencing another common assembly (with some interface definitions, enums, etc).

Is it possible to add UserControls to the Visual Studio toolbox if they are contained in assembly A, which references assembly B?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems it is possible to add UserControls to the Visual Studio toolbox if their assembly depends on another assembly. In the 'Choose Toolbox Items' -> Browse dialog, you need to multi-select the dll containing the user controls AND the dll it depends on, then click 'Open'.

Answer (score 0):

it is possible to get usercontrol from different assemblies just pass the assembly name where you got user user control by left click on toolbar --> add user control -->> new user control